# How checking font size mobile device with nativescript

Tags: fonts, nativescript

I have problem with font size in android. If you change font size in setting. its will change font size in application. How to responsive font size on font setting.

Comment: By default {N} Android uses SP unit so it will scale accordingly based on device preference. Do you want to stop it?

Comment: No, I have a problem with ui font on android user change font size to bigger font than usually used

Comment: Can you explain your problem statement? Also the kind of solution you prefer, that helps to take it further.

Comment: Example, I set size `font-size: 20;` then text will show size 20dpi that will fit all device in case font display default in android but on Font size bigger than default like large or largest. Its will over size on UI (You can change by Setting => Display => Font Size)

Comment: Yes I understand that. But what do you prefer, back to my first question - do you like to prevent it, stop responding to device preferences?

Comment: I don't like to prevent it because It's will effective on user then I want to know and change font size by base on font size setting

Comment: Did you ever figure out this ? my daughter's font in her settings are huge, and my entire app looks funny. makes me wonder if it's better to place the text as Image ( which scale per width of the phone vs font size )